# python 2.7 - setting up 2 loggers

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, python-2.x

I'me trying to setup 2 loggers, unfortunately one of them doesn't write into the file, Here is a snippet of my code:

```
LOG_FILENAME = 'test.log'
LOG_FILENAME2 = 'test2.log'
error_counter = 0
error_logger = CustomLogger(LOG_FILENAME2, 'w', '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s -  %(message)s',
                            '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')
error_logger.set_level('info')
error_logger.basic_config()
print "This is the first logger: {0}".format(error_logger.get_file_path)
error_logger.log_message("This is a test message of the first instance")

warning_logger = CustomLogger(LOG_FILENAME, 'w', '%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s -  %(message)s',
                              '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S')

warning_logger.set_level('warning')
warning_logger.basic_config()
print "This is the the second logger: {0} ".format(warning_logger.get_file_path)
warning_logger.log_message("this is a test message of the second instance")
```

Here is the custom class that i've created:

```
class CustomLogger(object):

    LEVELS = {'debug': logging.DEBUG,
              'info': logging.INFO,
              'warning': logging.WARNING,
              'error': logging.ERROR,
              'critical': logging.CRITICAL}

    def __init__(self, i_file_path=None, i_filemode=None, i_format=None, i_date_format=None, i_log_level=None):

        self.__file_path = i_file_path
        self.__filemode = i_filemode
        self.__format = i_format
        self.__date_format = i_date_format
        self.__log_level = i_log_level

def basic_config(self):
        logging.basicConfig(
            filename=self.__file_path,
            filemode=self.__filemode,
            format=self.__format,
            datefmt=self.__date_format,
            level=self.__log_level
            )
def log_message(self, i_message):
        try:
            if None in (self.__file_path, self.__log_level, self.__filemode, self.__date_format, self.__format):
                raise ErrorLoggerPropertiesRequiredException()
        except ErrorLoggerPropertiesRequiredException as e:
            print "{0}".format(e.message)
        else:
            curr_logger = logging.getLogger(self.__file_path)
            print "writing to log {0}".format(i_message)
            curr_logger.log(self.__log_level, i_message)
```

It's creating and writing only to the first logger, i've tried many things i saw on [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html) that there is another property called `disable_existing_loggers` which is by default True, i;ve tried accessing this property using `logging.config.fileConfig(fname, defaults=None, disable_existing_loggers=False)`, but it seems that there is no such method.

Comment: I believe logging.basicConfig() just configures the 'root' logger.  What you need is logging.getLogger('enter some name here') and take a slightly more manual approach to building the 2 loggers.

Comment: Could you provide me some example ?
BTW, should i change all the code written here?

Comment: You are not supposed to instantiate Logger classes by hand.  You're meant to use [`setLoggerClass()`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/logging.html#logging.setLoggerClass) and `getLogger()`.

Comment: addressing the lack of logging.config.fileConfig(), you need to explicitly import logging.config

Comment: I've solved it using 2 custom handlers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are running into a problem I have run into many times:

logging.basicConfig()

is calling the module level configuration, and, according to the docs:

> This function does nothing if the root logger already has handlers
>   configured for it.

In other words, it will only have an effect the first time it is called.
This function is only meant as a "last resort" config, if I understand it correctly.

You should instead configure each logger based on the "self" reference, rather than the global basic config...

A basic pattern I use for each module level logger is (note the import statement!):

```
import logging.config
try:
       logging.config.fileConfig('loggingpy.conf', disable_existing_loggers=False)
except Exception as e:
    # try to set up a default logger
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO,
                        format="%(asctime)s:%(name)s:%(lineno)d %(levelname)s : %(message)s")
main_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

I am sure I copied this from somewhere...

Comment: I've tried something like this:
`logger = logging.getLogger('test_logger')
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler1 = logging.FileHandler('logger_debug.log')
handler1.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler2 = logging.FileHandler('logger_error.log')
handler2.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s -  %(message)s')
handler1.setFormatter(formatter)
handler2.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler1)
logger.addHandler(handler2)
logger.debug('debug message')
logger.error('error message')
logger.info('info message')`